# Changing JSESSIONID in aws does not log me out

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jsessionid

I am using aws and I decided to take a look what they store in the cookies. I saw JSESSIONID there,which means that they are using java. To my suprise,when I removed JSESSIONID It DID NOT log me out, but when I removed the cookie called AWS-USERINFO it DID log me out? My questions is 
why removing JSESSEIONID  does not log me out, and removing aws-userinfo does?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, They are using the `JSESSIONID` to other authorization or validation and lastly AWS don't want you to know that.